# Conditions in multiple functions (python)

Tags: python, function

I have this code, but why when the time reach 0:30 nothing happens, where is my error?:

```
import datetime

def a():

   timing = [0, 30] #hours, #minutes
   while True:
       now = datetime.datetime.now()
       datas = [now.hour, now.minute]    
       if datas == timing:
            a.x = 5
        
def b():
    a()
    if "he" == "he":
        print(2)
    
         if a.x == 5:
             print("VER")
    
b()
```

Comment: Are you defining "a.x" within a()? Because you can only do that within classes, not functions.

Comment: You never break out of the `while` loop, so `a()` never returns.

Comment: @GIOVANNIQUINONESVALDEZ Functions are class instance, so you can create attributes on them.

Comment: @Barmar You are right1

Comment: Add `break` or `return` to the `if` block in `a()`.

Comment: what are you trying to do exactly? maybe there's a best solution design that can simplify the problem

Comment: @Barmar I tried to insert "break" under a.x = 5, but still it doesnt work, nothing happens, I will try to insert in the b function, thanks

Comment: Did you wait until 30 minutes after midnight?

Comment: @Barmar I can always modify the hour inside the list, i can try it every minute

Comment: Add `print(datas, timing)` to the loop.

Comment: @UlisesBussi I want that the code prints 2 and then "VER". I have more complex code than this

Comment: @Barmar I tried to add print(datas, timing) under a.x = 5 (first function), but still nothing..

Comment: No, put it before `if datas == timing:`

Comment: @Barmar Okok I solved, I had to put the "break" it did not work before because i had to restart the kernel, thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe because you don't leave the while loop. You should add a `break` to `if` condition. It means if `a.x` is set, then program should leave the function `a` and get back to function `b`.

```py
def a():

   timing = [18, 54] #hours, #minutes
   while True:
       now = datetime.datetime.now()
       datas = [now.hour, now.minute]    
       if datas == timing:
            a.x = 5
            break
        
def b():
    a()
    if "he" == "he":
        print(2)
    
        if a.x == 5:
            print("VER")
    
b()
```

Comment: he said he tried this and it didn't work.

Comment: Are you sure you change the values in `timing` based on the current time? I mean if you run the code now, nothing happens till we get `datas == timing`. So for testing, you should change the `timing`!

Comment: See his last comment. It did work, he just forgot to restart after editing.

Comment: @amir It works thanks, and what if i want to avoid the "break",is there a way to run the functions without the "break"?

Comment: @TreesJin you can use `return` instead of `break`